# Using Vcpkg in Windows + Visual Studio environment, how to add "VERSIONINFO" resource to the VCPKG linked DLLs?

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit, visual-studio-2022, vcpkg

I use vcpkg to get the 3rd party "cpprestsdk" for my Windows Visual Studio 2022 environment.
The VCPKG downloads, setup, and compile the package elegantly, everything goes well, there is no any compile or link problems.

But I would like to use the CPPRest_.dll (not the static library version of it), because I already have several own DLLs in the project, so I do not want to duplicate the CPPRest codes into each own dlls - that's why I use the CPPRestSDK dynamic version, not the static one.

So, there will be a CPPRest.dll, and several others DLLs written by me (aka. our team).

The question is: how can I add resources like "VERSIONINFO" -> "ProductName", "ProductVersion" to the CPPRest.dll?
Where can I set-up these info for the VCPKG.EXE?

Which I tried:
Downloaded the VCPKG itself - as it described, then I ese the command line:

> vcpkg.exe install cpprestsdk --triplet x64-windows

After this finished I already get the installed folder, and there is the "installed\x64-windows\bin\cpprest_2_10.dll" -> seems ok.
But there is no "VERSIONINFO" in it.

Expected:
I would like to set-up some resources (like Windows' *.rc file) which should be linked, included into the cpprest_2_10.DLL.

Answer (score 0):

vcpkg is mainly used to manage dependencies of C++ libraries. It does not provide functionality to add rc files. You need to add the rc file to cpprestsdk and build it yourself.

https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk

Comment: Hi, @György Reisch  May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?